# How do i get content into my projectpages? (data-url)

Tags: data-url

I have an issue getting content inside the projectpages. (I literally tried to figure this out for 4 days now, searching the web - i will give my right arm for solving this)

So I have a simple index.html page with 7 projects (7 thumb images representing each portfolio project). When i click on one of the images i would like to get to the page showing its content - i get to the new page /#/WORK1/ but i can't figure out where/how to insert my content in this new url?

You can see the problem at my site here:
[awesth.dk](http://awesth.dk)

Here is the code i am using for the 7 projects. WORK1, WORK2 etc.

```
<div id="projectPages">

 <div class="project page-project" data-url="/WORK1/" >

    <!-- Will be fetched on-demand -->

 </div>
 ...
```

(So I don't know how I get it to be "fetched on-demand")

And here is the 7 clickable thumbs:

```
<div id="projectThumbs" >
 <div class="wrapper">

   <a class="project "href="/WORK1/" >
    <div>
      <div class="project-image"><div class="intrinsic"><div class="content-fill"><img data-src="/img/upcoming.png" data-image="/img/upcoming.png" data-image-dimensions="2500x1401" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" alt="work"  data-load="false"/><noscript><img src="/img/upcoming.png"></noscript></div></div><div class="project-item-count">0</div></div>   
      <div class="project-title">Titel1</div>
    </div>
   </a>
   ...
```

Pleaaase help

Comment: What do you actually mean by "fetched on-demand"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use write some JavaScript code using JQuery.

There are methods you need:

1. [click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) – to add click event handler.
2. [data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) – to get value from `data` attribute.
3. [load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) – to load contents from some URL to some element.

**UPD**

There is an example of using these methods. Does it fit your case?

https://jsfiddle.net/up495fzs/

**UPD2**

You need to update your HTML code on the server.

Pay attention to `data-project-id="1"` and `id="project-id-1"`. And update numbers respectively.

In `data-url` set your relative path. If you want to load `WORK1.html` file, you should write: `data-url='/WORK1.html'` (without `/` at the end).

**UPD3**

The connection between blocks are made by `data-project-id="1"` and `id="project-id-1"` attributes.

I change the way to get url. I leave it in `<a href="...">` and removed from `<div class="project page-project">`.

https://jsfiddle.net/up495fzs/6/

But for now I realised that I don't understand why you need many `<div class="project page-project">` elements. Why not to use just one?

https://jsfiddle.net/up495fzs/5/

**UPD4**

And you need to know about CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing) – https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

You could load contents just from your web site. It'll fail if you will try to load page from external web site.

**UPD4**

You could use `history.pushState(null, null, link.href);` to update the URL of the page.

http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Updated JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/up495fzs/8/

**You won't see URL changes at JSFiddle because it runs in a frame.**
Try it on your page.

**UPD5**

1. Add link to JQuery library to the `<head>` of your page but before my script.
2. Add my script wrapped with `$(function() { /* JS code */ });` to execute it properly.

   ```
   <head>
   ...
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ...
   <script>
     $(function() {
       /* JS code from JSFiddle */
     });
   </script>
   ```

Comment: You need to provide more complete code. Please update that JSFiddle with your HTML code.

Comment: I see the example is working at jsfiddle - but unfortunately I can't get it to work at my page even if i copy the html from jsfiddle and put the JQuery in top of my <head>. If i do so, my thumb suddenly isn't clickable anymore?

In the jsfiddle example you wrote: data-url="/user/login/"  - and then it shows the user login to jsfiddle. (perfect) So do i replace it with an html page i upload to my server? 

Example: I upload WORK1.html to my server and write data-url="/WORK1.html/" ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Aske_W/up495fzs/2/ with all i got from my body. Im only working on the first thumb right now: data-project-id="1" and id="project-id-1" (sorry im still new noob at this so something is messy i guess)

Comment: @AskeW Please provide new link for JSFiddle.

Comment: I tried to put both of your JSFiddle example in. But as you can see on my site right now awesth.dk, it does only change the URL to http://awesth.dk/#/WORK1.html when i press the thumb. It dosn't go into the "project page". I must do something wrong? :/  I really appreciate your help and time!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch you. There is no code in my JSFiddle about URL.

Comment: Okay i tried the new JSFiddle but it dosn't make any different unfortunately? - Yes i could delete it all and make a simple img link to every new projectpage i guess.. it would just be so much better to get this to work. It is so close :)

Comment: You could not see last JSFiddle working at jsfiddle.com side. There is no such html pages you referenced in your `<a>` links. And there is a frame which hides the URL updating. You need to use the code on your page.

Comment: I did try to put the JSFiddle code into my site, but it dosn't make any different. 
- I made this test page: awesth.dk/WORK1.html where i just wrote hello world ( as a test). But as you can see when you press the first image - it just changes the URL to http://awesth.dk/#/WORK1.html without going anywhere.

Comment: I added the code and now the URL changes to http://awesth.dk/WORK1.html#/WORK1.html but it still don't go further.
I think maybe it could be because i have alot of code in the <head> that maybe interupt something. I am not really sure about every line in here. See the new JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Aske_W/up495fzs/9/
I put in everything from my head exept doctype